# Visual Studio Code take too much time for intelli-sense while I pressing Ctrl + space?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, artificial-intelligence

When I used visual code for react-native mobile development that time I suddenly facing this error like intelli-sense are not worked that wise I write all code manually so how can I fix my issue?

[image: As per showing below image]

Comment: Try installing plugin for react-native

Comment: well it's an internal vscode issue. it happens with me just close and launch it again will fix the issue as well take into consideration that the huge load of extensions might cause this issue as well ( like a little conflict)

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875064/12434428

Answer (score 0):

Because of I used country-picker-model with lots of JSON format data so when removed country-picker model dependency then all of intelli-sense are active.