# In VS Code suggestions are coming in 3-4 second later

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VS Code suggestions are coming in 3-4 second later only in Nodejs Project . What is the reason for such slowness? Please Let me know if anyone knows the solution....

Gif of Problem: [Problem Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiKpm.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling any unwanted extensions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874486/visual-studio-code-intellisense-is-very-slow-is-there-anything-i-can-do) is a similar post.

If this doesn't work go for [reinstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461400/how-to-completely-remove-vs-code-setting/52462074) it.

Comment: I already tried these methods, but not worked. Now my vs code have no extensions, fully fresh.